# Spanish accent mark using HtmlHelper in CakePHP 1.2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I am reading the documentation at https://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/HTML.html#link, and I see this:

```
link(string $title, mixed $url = null, array $htmlAttributes = array(), string $confirmMessage = false, boolean $escapeTitle = true)
```

`string $title` is where I want to put text with a Spanish accent mark. The text is `aquí`, so I tried using `aqu&iacute;` and it did not work. Using `aquí` did not work either. In the first case the result was this the website printing exactly `aqu&iacute;`. In the second case, the text was not even displayed at all. How can I print Spanish accent marks or in general, Spanish special characters, using the HtmlHelper in CakePHP 1.2? Thank you.

Comment: Passing `aquí` should work fine. Make sure that the encoding of your template/view file matches your application's encoding (`App.encoding`, defaults to `UTF-8`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it works correctly for me now:

```
<span class="bold">
    <?php echo  $html->link('aqu&iacute;', array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'change_product'), array('target' => '_self', 'class'=>'js-thickbox', 'escape' => false)); ?>
</span>
```

Comment: This is a workaround to encode Spanish as US-ASCII. The trick works in HTML but not in plain text or other contexts. A database driven application that needs to handle Spanish data should really work with a Spanish-compatible encoding like ISO-8859-1 or (the best option) UTF-8.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Good point. But the workaround was the solution for me at least for now. Thanks.